# gitlab generates no passwords

Tags: email, passwords, gitlab

I installed gitlab 6.2 on my server as seen here [installation.md](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/6-2-stable/doc/install/installation.md)

When I add a user via web interface the user receives the mail send by gitlab.
But without password.

> The Administrator created an account for you. Now you are a member of the company GitLab application.
>
> login.......................................... sample@domain.com
>
> password..................................
>
> You will be forced to change this password immediately after login.
>
> Click here to login

When I change the password of the user manually in the admin panel the login is successful.

In my gitlab.yml I have this:

> ## Users management
>
> # default: false - Account passwords are not sent via the email if signup is enabled.
>
> # signup_enabled: true

Comment: I could figure out that the password field in mysql is empty as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a bug in Gitlab 6.2. There is already a a bugfix for that in master branch: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/5436

You can apply this change manually to fix the problem.